# Passing data from one Pentaho transformation to another in a job?

Tags: pentaho, pdi, spoon

Fairly straightforward question I think, I just haven't been able to find a clear example. I have a very complex transformation that I'm breaking down into a job. Having never created a job before, I'm struggling to send the data from one transformation to another. I used Copy Rows to Result in the first one and Get Rows From Result in the second one, but I feel like I'm still missing something. When I used Get Rows, I had to specify the row names - there was no sort of Get Fields button. I also can't preview the data in the transformation without running the job and having it save to an Excel file. When I did that, ALL of the fields were in the output file -- instead of just the ones I'd specified in the second transformation.

I've searched through the documentation and tried Googling but I can't find a clear walkthrough just on how to smoothly move data from one transformation to another. Any responses would be appreciated even if it's just pointing me towards something I've overlooked.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The most commom way is to use copy rows to result at the end of one KTR and use get rows from result as the starting point for the next one. Though you really can't "see" the result while operating in the next KTR, what you can do to ease the reading is set a preview window and leave it open to see all the columns names and data.

Whoever if you want to set just a few lines of code through to the next KTR you can use Set variables as the ending step of the first KTR and capture those variables at anytime in the second using Get Variables steps. Don't forget that if you do so you need to set the variables in the parent KJB(the Job that called the first KTR) with no Default value, and the Variable scope type of the  Set variables step has to be set to Valid in the parent job.

Answer (score -3):

The best way is to create KTR's, run/test each. This way you can examine resulting data and then integrate all individual transformations into the final job.